# how to re-register the service worker with next-pwa

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, next-pwa

I am using `next-pwa` package with my next.js applications for PWA features. But I am having a problem here.
Everytime, I rebuild and redeploy the application, it doesn't re-register the service worker, so I don't get the updated data. I have to manually unregister the service worker and clear the chrome cache to get the updated data. How can I solve this?
Here's my PWA configuration in `next.config.js` file

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['i.ibb.co'],
  },
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['src'],
  },
  // pwa configuration
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public/pwa',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    runtimeCaching,
    buildExcludes: [
      /chunks\/images\/.*$/, // Don't precache files under .next/static/chunks/images this improves next-optimized-images behaviour
      /chunks\/pages\/api\/.*/, // Dont cache the API it needs fresh serverinfo
    ],
    exclude: [
      /\.map$/, // dont cache map files
      /^.*ts.*$/, // Dont let serviceworker touch the TS streams
      /-manifest.json$/, // exclude those pesky json files in _next root but still serve the ones we need from /_next/static
    ],
    skipWaiting: true, // installs new SW when available without a prompt, we only need to send a reload request to user.
    dynamicStartUrl: false, // recommend: set to false if your start url always returns same HTML document, then start url will be precached, this will help to speed up first load.
    reloadOnOnline: false, // Prevents reloads on offline/online switch
    sourcemap: false,
  },
})
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Check the Following answer and comments, they were helpful

Answer (score 1):

Once a service worker with a given URL and scope has been registered, there's no need to re-register it multiple times. Even if you never call `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` again in a given browser, the previous registration will remain active.

The Workbox documentation features a [section](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/service-worker-lifecycle/) detailing how a browser checks for service worker updates, and how that interacts with different configurations of Workbox.

Since you're using the `skipWaiting: true` configuration option, I would expect that after navigating to a page in your web app when there's already in a service worker in place, the cache entries will end up being swapped out "under the hood" automatically, and the *next* navigation you make to a new page within the service worker's scope will end up being fulfilled with the new resources. Be aware that `skipWaiting: true` means that this cache swap happens immediately after the updated service worker is installed, and this could be a bit unpredictable for existing open clients if you, e.g., [lazily-load assets](https://dev.to/jeffposnick/paying-attention-while-loading-lazily-45ef).

There's [specific guidance](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/handling-service-worker-updates/) about how you can control when the updates to the cached resource by using `skipWaiting: false` and manually triggering the update in response to, e.g., a user opting-in. `next-pwa` may or may not have some components that help with this update flow—I'm not familiar with what it offers.

Comment: Thanks. But how does my website know that the data has changed and it needs to re-register the service worker once my rebuild my next.js website?

Comment: You should never need to re-register your service worker, unless you need to use a different URL or scope for the service worker script file. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/service-worker-lifecycle/#when-updates-happen describes how updates happen, from the perspective of Workbox's precaching.

Comment: https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/#updates is a more generic description of how service worker updates happen, without referencing anything Workbox-specific.

Comment: But I don't think the cache is updating automatically, because I am seeing the previous version of the app even after re-deploying the next.js website. Basically, I want to update the cache every time I re-deploy or rebuild the website. How can I do that?